# Why does 'npm run develop' work while 'gatsby develop' throws error?

Tags: gatsby

Running **'gatsby develop' on console gives below error** but 'npm run develop' as well as 'gatsby develop' when deploying to netlify **works fine**. Can someone explain why this is?

**Error when running gatsby develop:**

```
Problems with gatsby-source-contentful plugin options:
spaceId: undefined - "spaceId" is required
accessToken: undefined - "accessToken" is required
```

even though tokens are defined in .env.development and plugins options set:

```
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-contentful',
      options: {
        spaceId: process.env.CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID,
        accessToken: process.env.CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN
      }
```

Comment: Do you have gatsby-cli installed as a global package? Usually running gatsby directly is calling the global cli and might not find the env variables while npm run will run the local copy inside your project folder. I mean, this is not supposed to happen, but might be the case.

Comment: I did have it installed as global. I tried uninstalling it, reinstalling for the project dir only and the same behavior persist (I tried this first with npm and then with yarn for good measure). So still a mystery to me, but working with gatsby does work as long as run through npm or yarn. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: Are you able to add the scripts section of your `package.json`?

Comment: `  "scripts": {
    "build": "gatsby build",
    "develop": "env-cmd -f .env.development gatsby develop",
    "format": "prettier --write \"**/*.{js,jsx,json,md}\"",
    "start": "npm run develop",
    "serve": "gatsby serve",
    "clean": "gatsby clean",
    "test": "echo \"Write tests! -> https://gatsby.dev/unit-testing\" && exit 1"
  },`

Comment: oh my, starting at the basics here :D that won't format correctly. Anyway, would I be rigth to assume that the answer is related to `"start": "npm run develop",`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
require("dotenv").config({
path: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
})

module.exports = {
 siteMetadata: { ... },
 plugins: [
   ...
  `gatsby-transformer-remark`,
{
  resolve: `gatsby-source-contentful`,
  options: {
    spaceId: process.env.CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID,
    accessToken: process.env.CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN,
  },
},
...
 ]
}
```

Juse make sure you specify your .env path by adding those code. Error is because it can't locate the spaceId and accessToken.